# Can't refresh image on pythonanywhere website

Tags: django, pythonanywhere, django-staticfiles

Good evening!
I have created a webapp using Django framework.
I have **replaced a file in the /static/ folder locally** (and put the same name for the new file). Then I **pushed those changes to my GitHub rep**o and **pulled** them using bash console **for my pythinanywюhere web app**. Then I tried to reload the page, but I *got the following message* on **pythonanywhere**: "Your webapp took a long time to reload. It probably reloaded, but we were unable to check it".

The file was not replaced and the webpage shows and old version of image.

What should I do with this situation? I can't even suggest what the problem is.

Comment: It's possible that your browser is caching it. Try hard reload.

Comment: Just to add to that -- to do a hard reload, hold down the shift button while you click the reload button in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

The webpage will show older image until you reload your application.

But since you can't reload, it's showing older image.

I'm having same issue on my webApp on pythonAnywhere about reloading.

It has happened before. It's the problem with their servers. Wait until they solve it.

[pythonAnywhere forum](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/12986/)

```
Thanks for reporting. We had a problem with one of our servers,
it's fixed now. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
```